# Bind System related information in WPF using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I wish to list out the **Temp files** in the **WPF XAML using MVVM Binding** with **`INotifyPropertyChanged`**.

The View Model is **TempViewModel.cs**

```
class TempViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<FileInfo> CacheFiles
    {
        get
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            return di.GetFiles().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The Files in the Temp Folder may vary on time to time. I need to update it automatically, whenever the files updated in the Temp folder using **`INotifyPropertyChanged`** in the XAML UI

How could I bind it in the XMAL ?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="LstProduct" ItemsSource="{Binding CacheFiles}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new TempViewModel();
    }
}
```

I can't able to get the updated FileName List in the UI. Kindly assist me, how to update UI, whenever the files added or deleted in the Temp Folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **`FileSystemWatcher`**

You should modify your **TempViewModel.cs**

```
class Cleaner : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> _memoryPool = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> MemoryPool
    {
        get { return _memoryPool; }
        set
        {
            _memoryPool = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MemoryPool"));
        }
    }


    private void watch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCollection();
    }

    private void UpdateCollection()
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        CacheFiles = di.GetFiles().ToList();
    }

    public Cleaner()
    {
        UpdateCollection();
        watch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FileSystemWatcher`([see the docs for how to use it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)) and subscribe to one of its events. In that handler call the `PropertyChanged` event with `"CacheFiles"` to signal the UI to re-get the `CacheFiles` property.

You can certainly improve on this with an `ObservableCollection` and manually adding/removing entries to that, but the way I described should work.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate it please, in terms of code ?

Comment: within two minutes you got two _very_ similar answers. This suggests, that this is not very hard to do. I will not supply the whole code. I suggest you read up on the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and then try it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You should use FileSystemWatcher and [Changed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, when FileSystemWatcher raise Changed event, you event handler should change CacheFile property with raising PropertyChanged

Comment: can you kindly elaborate it please, in terms of code ?